# Wordpress/Codeigniter URL issues when installed on same server

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I have installed my wordpress installation on my server root **e.g mydomain.com** & codeigniter installed in subdirectory named ci **e.g mydomain.com/ci**. When I try to access my wordpress site it works fine, but when I try to access any of my ci controllers e.g mydomain.com/ci/signup it throw 404 Page Not Found CI error. but it worked fine for my default home controller. I have searched for solution & tried many of them but any one of them is not worked in my case.

here is the rewrite rules in .htaccess for my both installtion.

**mydomain.com/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**mydomain.com/ci/.htaccess**

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /ci
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|user_guide|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with wordpress .htaccess file. We should have to route the request that is for **ci** to ci folder.

This code might help, add this to wordpress .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^$ ci/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) ci/$1 [L]
```

Comment: As I put the above code on wordpress .htaccess, but when i try to access my wordpress site it redirects to ci default controller. means now when try to access my domain root it loads my ci site.

Comment: can you  please share your wordpress .htaccess file ?

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ ci/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) ci/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>